# How do you call a php function from a javascript function and pass a variable at the same time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, function

Right now I have this:

```
  var ajax = getRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajax.readyState == 4){
          document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }
  }
  ajax.open("GET", "get_schedule.php", true);
  ajax.send(null);
  }

        function getRequest() {
        var req = false;
        try{
            // most browsers
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
            // IE
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                // try an older version
                try{
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return req;
    }
```

which allows me to call a php file with code get_schedule.php. However I would like to pass a variable along with the ajax function. I am pretty new to Ajax, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `GET`, you pass parameters by appending them to the URL:

```
ajax.open("GET", "get_schedule.php?paramname=" + encodeURIComponent(paramvalue), true);
```